# how to implement register_next_step_handler in c# (Telegram bot)?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

I need to register next user message. In python telebot there is register_next_step_handler, but i don`t see it in c#.
so far I only thought of creating a variable and assigning it like this:

`count = 15 + Convert.ToInt32(callback.Message.Chat.Id);`

and after in message event i check, if variable equals to 15 + %message%.Chat.Id, something like this:

```
if (count == 15 + msg.Chat.Id)
{
//some stuff to do here. 
}
```

But there`s a problem:

The user may not respond and the variable will be infinitely occupied by one and other users will not be able to use commands that require additional input

Comment: Hello Snail, maybe in stead of creating just one variable you could create a Diccionary that suports every state of any user, using the tuppla "user_id", "user_state". Do you think I could be useful?